# How to extend arbor base?

Tags: wood

Our garden arbor's underground legs are completely rotted and the arbor has fallen. I wonder what's the best way to fix it. I am thinking in extending the above-ground part of the legs (which are in good state) with new wood, attach it with steel plates, and bury it again. Any other idea? There is no concrete as in fence posts, just the bare wooden legs into the ground, so I am not sure fence post menders could help. The four legs are 3-1/4in x 1-1/2in each. It is a relatively light arbor. Can be lifted by one person.

[image: Underground part is ~1' long, but it was too rotten to know for sure]

[image: Complete Arbor]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture or two would really help us understand your situation.

Comment: Thanks! Updated post with photos. Underground part is around 1', but not 100% sure as it was too rotten

Answer (score 1):

I would use "Post spikes" for this. They'll last longer than wood below ground.

[image]

Comment: I have used these a few times. as light as the arbor is i think they would work fine.

Comment: Thanks! But the legs are 3-1/4in x 1-1/2in, not square. Would these still work?

Comment: @ACP - If you can't find spikes that will fit your lumber, you can cut some filler pieces to fill the rest of the post spike. I'd imagine you'll find some that fit, though, if you notice, the one on the right appears round, so they do come in different sizes/shapes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there isn't much weight to be dealt with, although appearance is important. How about setting the arbor on pressure-treated sections of 2x4? Specifically:

1. Measure the existing rotten ends of the arbor, keeping track of where the ground level was in relation to the arbor
2. Cut off the rotten ends of the arbor to make the ends clean
3. Take sections of pressure-treated 2x4 and embed them vertically into the ground where the arbor will sit, so that they're placed right where the original 2x4 legs were. Set them so that the newly-clean ends of the arbor legs will sit on them, with the PT 2x4s extending the length of the arbor legs and with the arbor at the correct height (as measured above).
4. Fasten the arbor legs to the PT 2x4 sections. Possibilities include mending plates, 1' sections of rebar set into holes drilled lengthwise into the center of the PT wood and arbor legs, or tying them together with (rot-proof) string between holes in the arbor legs and the PT 2x4s. Your biggest concern will be wind blowing the arbor over, so plan the connection strength accordingly. Or, just be ready to stand the arbor back up if it ever happens.